# Getting the Average time of per day in a month - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this data in my system. Having the duration column in a `NVARCHAR` type.

```
 | Site | Application |    Time Checked    | Duration |
 ------------------------------------------------------
    A        AAAA       1/11/2016 12:00AM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/11/2016 12:00AM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/11/2016 12:00AM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/11/2016 12:00AM      4.0s
    A        AAAA       1/11/2016 12:30AM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/11/2016 12:30AM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/11/2016 12:30AM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/11/2016 12:30AM      4.0s
 ......................................................
    A        AAAA       1/11/2016 11:00PM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/11/2016 11:00PM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/11/2016 11:00PM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/11/2016 11:00PM      4.0s
    A        AAAA       1/11/2016 11:30PM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/11/2016 11:30PM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/11/2016 11:30PM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/11/2016 11:30PM      4.0s
    A        AAAA       1/12/2016 12:00AM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/12/2016 12:00AM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/12/2016 12:00AM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/12/2016 12:00AM      4.0s
    A        AAAA       1/12/2016 12:30AM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/12/2016 12:30AM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/12/2016 12:30AM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/12/2016 12:30AM      4.0s
 ......................................................
    A        AAAA       1/12/2016 11:00PM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/12/2016 11:00PM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/12/2016 11:00PM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/12/2016 11:00PM      4.0s
    A        AAAA       1/12/2016 11:30PM      5.0s
    B        AAAA       1/12/2016 11:30PM      4.0s
    A        BBBB       1/12/2016 11:30PM      5.0s
    B        BBBB       1/12/2016 11:30PM      4.0s
```

Every day my system checks the duration 2 times per hour (which starts with NN:00 AM/PM and next is NN:30 AM/PM) And I need to get the total average of the duration per day in different sites and application in the whole month.

Like this

```
 | (Site A) Ave.Duration | Day Time Checked | Application |
          5.4 s               1/11/2016          AAAA
          5.4 s               1/12/2016          AAAA
          5.4 s               1/13/2016          AAAA
 ..........................................................
          5.4 s               1/11/2016          BBBB
          5.4 s               1/12/2016          BBBB
          5.4 s               1/13/2016          BBBB
 ..........................................................
```

Can somebody help me with this? I already gone through different questions here.

But I still don't quite get it.

Your answer will be a great help.

Comment: Storing the duration in VARCHAR column is a bad idea. Why not use an INT column?

Comment: Then take a look at the [AVG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx) function.

Comment: @TT I know it's a bad idea. :) Thanks for reminding me. But I do really need a help for that output.

Comment: The link has plenty of good examples. Try something and if that fails, [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/273645) your question to include what you tried. We can help your from there. GL!

Comment: @TT Thanks. I'll try it

Comment: @TT I try the codes. But still get the wrong output. Maybe because of my logic level :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:A full [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/423501#resultSets)

```
create table 
#test1
(
site char(1),
apl char(10),
timechecked datetime,
duration real,
)

insert into #test1
select 
'A','AAAA','1/11/2016 12:00AM',5.0s
union all
select
'B','BBBB','1/11/2016 12:30AM',4.0s
union all
select 
'A','BBBB','1/12/2016 12:00AM',5.0s

--nromal method
;with cte
as
(
select duration,convert(varchar(2),datepart(day,timechecked))+'/'+
convert(varchar(2),datepart(month,timechecked))+'/'+
convert(varchar(4),datepart(year,timechecked)) as datetimee,
apl
from
#test1
)
select 
avg(duration) as avgduration,
datetimee,apl
from
cte
group by datetimee,apl

---using window functions
;with cte
as
(
select duration,convert(varchar(2),datepart(day,timechecked))+'/'+
convert(varchar(2),datepart(month,timechecked))+'/'+
convert(varchar(4),datepart(year,timechecked)) as datetimee,
apl
from
#test1
)

select
avg(duration) over (partition by datetimee order by datetimee ) as avgduration,
datetimee,
apl
from cte
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll try this one

Comment: BTW the duration column is a NVARCHAR type. Typographical error in my post. Sorry. Anyways. I try your codes and it works on the Table Created in #Test1 but when I try it on my database. There's an error saying "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: @Elphrian Your first reaction should be to change the column to contain INT values! Why make it hard on yourself? If you want to visualize the seconds in your program, add that `s` in the presentation layer.